# php: return compact() value from inside a function

Tags: php

I want to know why php global function compact() only return empty array when used inside a function.

Here is the code as an example:

```
$hello = "world";

function myFunc($str) {
    return compact($str);
}

$arr = myFunc('hello');

print_r($arr);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: `$hello` is simply not in scope inside `myFunc`.

Answer (score 1):

variable $hello scope issue
try this:

```
$hello = "world";

$myFunc = function($str) use($hello) {
    return compact($str);
};
print_r($myFunc('hello'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`compact()` function is an inbuilt function in PHP and it is used to create an array using variables. This function is opposite of extract() function. It creates an associative array whose keys are variable names and their corresponding values are array values.

you are passing variable like this `compact($str)`, but in `compact` we used pass parameter like this (in `single quote` without `$` sign)

```
compact('str');
```

know your code look like this

```
$hello = "world";

function myFunc($str) {
    return compact('str');//compact('str'): means passing $str variable
}

$arr = myFunc('hello');//or myFunc($hello); (myFunc('hello'): means passing hello string and myFunc($hello): means passing $hello variable)
print_r($arr);
```

[check output](https://rextester.com/XSLZ43498)

If you have multiple variables then used `,` like this

```
$f_name='john';
$l_name='smith';
$address='xyz';

$result = compact("f_name", "l_name", "address");

print_r($result);
```

**Parameters:** This function accepts a variable number of arguments separated by comma operator `(',')`. These arguments are of string data type and specify the name of variables which we want to use to create the array. We can also pass an array as an argument to this function, in that case, all of the elements in the array passed as a parameter will be added to the output array.

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-compact-function/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, buddy. But you probably misunderstood my question or i forgot to mention the output expected as `Array([hello] => world)`. But your suggestion code gave output as `Array([str] => hello)`. Thankfully, suresh and david had solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `myFunc` isn't in the global scope, and can't access the `$hello` variable. Think about this code:

```
$hello = "world";
function myFunc () {
    echo $hello;
}
myFunc(); // => PHP: Undefined variable: hello
```

`myFunc` simply can't access the global variable `$hello`. However, if you add a `global` statement in the function, you *can* access the global scope:

```
$hello = "world";
function myFunc () {
    global $hello;
    echo $hello;
}
myFunc(); // => world
```

So, in summary, if you add a `global` to the top of your function, your function can work as expected:

```
$hello = "world";

function myFunc ($str) {
    global $hello;
    return compact($str);
}

$arr = myFunc('hello');

print_r($arr); // => Array ( [hello] => world )
```

Here's some further information on variable scope: [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)